# CURL Command line to PHP?

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, command-line

I need to run `sudo ip netns exec protected curl` in my CURL script.

I can't figure out how to do this in PHP.

I use `exec()` as in the snippet below to no avail:

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => $URL,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept-Language: ' . $Params
    )
);

$ch = curl_init($ReceiverURL);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $content;
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
system('sudo ip netns exec protected curl');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, this is what I did, for anyone in the future that reads this. :)

```
      $descriptors = array(
          0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // STDIN
          1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // STDOUT
          2 => array('pipe', 'w')  // STDERR
      );

      $process = proc_open("sudo ip netns exec protected curl ".
          " --header \"Accept-Language: " . addslashes($Params) . "\" " . $ReceiverURL . ' -s 2>&1', $descriptors, $pipes);

      fclose($pipes[0]);

      $content = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
      fclose($pipes[1]);

      $error = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
      fclose($pipes[2]);

    return $content;
```